# Get SystemKernelDebuggerInformation with ZwQuerySystemInformation

Tags: c, windows, debugging, winapi

I've been trying to determine whether the program is running under a system-mode debugger by using the ZwQuerySystemInformation function call.

So far I have the following code where I'm loading the ntdll.dll library and getting the address of the ZwQuerySystemInformation. Then I must call the handle that I get back with the apropriate arguments to get the SystemKernelDebuggerInformation information.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winternl.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    /* load the ntdll.dll */
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary(_T("ntdll.dll"));
    FARPROC fun = GetProcAddress(lib, "ZwQuerySystemInformation");
    if(fun == NULL) {
        printf("Error: could not find the function ZwQuerySystemInformation in library ntdll.dll.");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("ZwQuerySystemInformation is located at 0x%08x in ntdll.dll.\n", (unsigned int)fun);


    SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS sic = SystemKernelDebuggerInformation;
    SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION sbi;

    NTSTATUS WINAPI temp = NtQuerySystemInformation(sic, &sbi, sizeof(sbi), NULL);


    /* wait */
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Can you tell me how can I call that function to get the system information containing the SystemKernelDebuggerInformation information? That would be sufficient, I'll take care of the rest.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look at [CheckDebugger_Method3](http://shangdi.googlecode.com/svn-history/r343/trunk/code/LicenseLib/AntiDebug.cpp)

```
     int main(){
    typedef long NTSTATUS; 
    #define STATUS_SUCCESS    ((NTSTATUS)0L) 
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    typedef struct _SYSTEM_KERNEL_DEBUGGER_INFORMATION { 
                 BOOLEAN DebuggerEnabled; 
                 BOOLEAN DebuggerNotPresent; 
    } SYSTEM_KERNEL_DEBUGGER_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_KERNEL_DEBUGGER_INFORMATION; 
    enum SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS { SystemKernelDebuggerInformation = 35 }; 
    typedef NTSTATUS  (__stdcall *ZW_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)(IN SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass, IN OUT PVOID SystemInformation, IN ULONG SystemInformationLength, OUT PULONG ReturnLength); 
    ZW_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION ZwQuerySystemInformation;
    SYSTEM_KERNEL_DEBUGGER_INFORMATION Info;
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll");
    if (!hModule) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    ZwQuerySystemInformation = (ZW_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)GetProcAddress(hModule, "ZwQuerySystemInformation");
    if (ZwQuerySystemInformation) {
        if (STATUS_SUCCESS == ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemKernelDebuggerInformation, &Info, sizeof(Info), NULL)) {
            if (Info.DebuggerEnabled&&!Info.DebuggerNotPresent) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

[ZwQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is no longer available for use as of Windows 8